# Powershell: Redirecting stderr causes an exception

Tags: powershell

I encountered this behavior in Powershell and I was wondering why is this happening:

Running this script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference= "Stop"
cmd /c "echo error 1>&2" 2>log.txt
```

Produces the following output:

```
PS D:\playground\Powershell> .\Redirecting-Stderr.ps1
cmd : error
At D:\playground\Powershell\Redirecting-Stderr.ps1:3 char:1
+ cmd /c "echo error 1>&2" 2>log.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (error :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Actually, it doesn't matter what I'm redirecting to, it could be also $null, &1, etc.

Seems that the mere redirecting of stderr in powershell causes some exception to be raised. Why is that?

Powershell version: 5.1.17763.1490

Comment: why not putting as try catch block arround it ?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why this happening..

Comment: ok I gave up understanding Powershell is doing something, hopefully someone more clever can anser that

Comment: @user3732793 No, you're spot on!